# Why simply select a select syntax can save null?

Tags: mysql, select

This is a question from Leetcode:
[image]

I can't understand this approach, why it can overcome the issue?

[image]

I wonder the inside mechanism.

Comment: I'm still confused why we can't directly use the first approach. What does the select did for the select syntax within "()"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the first query is that it returns no rows if there is 1 row (or less) in the table.

It looks like they consider that an empty resultset is not the correct answer in this case. Instead, they always want one row as a result that contains a `null` value (which indicates the absence of the Nth salary in the table).

This is what the second query does. It `SELECT`s the (scalar) result of the initial query - so it always produces one row. If the subquery returns something, you get that value as a result, else you get `null`.

Consider this simple example:

```
select 1 where 0 = 1             -- returns no rows
select (select 1 where 0 = 1)    -- returns one row with a "null" value
```

Comment: WOW I got it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Salary AS SecondHighestSalary -- (DISTINCT is really not needed)
FROM Employee
ORDER BY Salary DESC
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
```

in case the table has only 1 row, does not return `null`.
It returns nothing (no rows).
But when it is placed inside another query as a derived column:

```
SELECT
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT Salary 
    FROM Employee
    ORDER BY Salary DESC
    LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
  ) AS SecondHighestSalary
```

the value of that column returned will be `null` because every column in a query contains either a value or `null` which has the meaning of *unknown* or *missing*.